# How to detect if SECOND sim has no service/signal?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

We ran into a problem where the 1st sim slot is empty and second slot has a sim. Using SubscriptionManager we can get the details of all sims using:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()

I thought that SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList() returns the sims that have signals but that wasn't the case it still return a list with a size of 1 (second sim with no signal).

However, we don't have anyway to check whether the second sim has a signal or not. SubscriptionInfo doesn't contain any status of the sim.